# How to merge two dataframes and return only matching rows/indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, `admissions` and `scholarship` with the following columns - `studentid`,`age`,`continent`,`sex`,`gpa`.

I want to do the following:

(I) append  `sex` and `gpa` values in `admissions` table to the corresponding rows in `scholarship` table, thereby returning only matching rows( index number)

(II) remove or avoid the `x` and `y` tags `age_x`, `continent_x` in the resulting columns where necessary

```
admissions 

 studentid, age,continent,sex,gpa
1, 10910, 18, Asia, F, 3.9 
2, 10014, 19, Europe, M, 3.8
3, 10121, 18, Africa, M, 3.9
4, 10333, 20, Asia, F, 4.0
5, 10215, 19, America, F, 3.8
```

```
scholarship

studentid, age,continent
1, 10910, 18, Asia
3, 10121, 18, Africa
4, 10333, 20, Asia
```

Desired outcome

```
scholarship_admissions
# take note of the index number
 studentid, age,continent,sex,gpa
1, 10910, 18, Asia, F, 3.9 
3, 10121, 18, Africa, M, 3.9
4, 10333, 20, Asia, F, 4.0
```

My attempt

```
Import pandas as pd

scholarship_admissions = pd.merge(admissions,scholarship,on = ‘studentid’,how = ‘inner’)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt looks good already, you can give a list as merge keys so you avoid the duplications of columns.

```
scholarship_admissions = admissions.merge(scholarship, left_on=["studentid", "age", "continent"], right_on=["studentid", "age", "continent"], how='inner')
```

Output:

```
   studentid  age continent sex  gpa
0      10910   18      Asia   F  3.9
1      10121   18    Africa   M  3.9
2      10333   20      Asia   F  4.0
```

And in order to keep the original index, you can add it as column and reapply after the merge.

```
scholarship_admissions_with_index = admissions.reset_index().merge(scholarship, left_on=["studentid", "age", "continent"], right_on=["studentid", "age", "continent"], how='inner').set_index('index')
```

Output:

```
       studentid  age continent sex  gpa
index                                   
0          10910   18      Asia   F  3.9
2          10121   18    Africa   M  3.9
3          10333   20      Asia   F  4.0
```

Instead of specifying `left_on` and `right_on`, in this specific case you can just use `on` as the columns have the same name in both DataFrames.

```
admissions.merge(scholarship, on=["studentid", "age", "continent"], how='inner')
```

Comment: Thanks once again! you are a lifesaver!